# C# Autofit method for excel sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am creating an excel sheet using C# .net. In the end I want to autofit the columns.
I am using following code.

```
    sheet0.Cells["A2:B2"].Columns.AutoFit();
```

But it is is thorowing an exception.
Can anyone help me solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: Please add more details. What exception? Stacktrace etc.

Comment: Does this work: `sheet0.Columns("A:B").AutoFit()`?

Comment: Do you use any third-party library?

Comment: with this (sheet0.Cells["A2:B2"].Columns.AutoFit();) you are trying to auto fit just two cells not columns. thats why you are getting that exception.

Comment: I got the exception to go away by changing it to this format:
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1][10].Columns.AutoFit();
However, it still doesn't autofit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
sheet0.Columns["A:B"].AutoFit();
```

Comment: For me, calling Autofit in this way does nothing. Is there a way to resize the widths of the columns programatically rather than relying on Autofit()?

Answer (score 23):

You can use:

```
sheet0.Columns.AutoFit();
```

---

This will re-size every column in this sheet to best fit.

**AutoFit Documentation:**

> Changes the width of the columns in the range or the height of the rows in the range to achieve the best fit.

Comment: This throws an exception for me.